# Exceptions don't work in C++ in XCode & Borland environments

Tags: c++, xcode, exception, divide-by-zero, borland-c++

I have a problem about (exceptions in C++).
I have been searching for a (long time) to find final solution for this problem; but still I could not find any thing.
I have read all answers but no benefit. I tried in C++ Xcode & C++ Borland !
why (try & catch) block does not work ?
Please I want to catch dividing by zero; how can I ?
thanks...

Comment: Division by zero isn't required to raise an exception. Your whole premise is wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller true in general, however in some Borland environments, they do intercept OS errors like divide-by-zero and convert them into normal C++ exceptions which can be caught. But this is handled at the RTL level, not the language level, and should not be relied on in portable code.